# Query Date Time Range with interval

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core-2.1

I want to query with a date time range with an interval of 10 seconds or more for each result. Is there a way where I can query using Linq or Expression in a single query without having to loop through all the results to do the interval.

ShipPosition Model Design

```
  - Id (int)
  - MMSI (int)
  - Latitude (decimal)
  - Longitude (decimal)
  - LocalRecvTime (datetime)
```

I'm still stuck what to do with this.

```
 dbContext.ShipPositions.Where(c => c.MMSI == m.MMSI &&
                        c.LocalRecvTime >= m.FromDateTime && c.LocalRecvTime < m.ToDateTime)
```

I expect the result should be something like this where the difference of Row 2 and Row 1 should be 10 seconds or more

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
<thead>
    <th>
      MMSI      
    </th>
     <th>
      Date Time      
    </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>14:10:23</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>14:10:33</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>14:10:46</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is it possible for there to be two equal timestamps?

Comment: Can you show the full definition of `ShipPositions`? Does it have a primary key?

Comment: @NetMage Nope. The result cannot have equal timestamps and yes, ShipPosition does have a primary key

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
var src = dbContext.ShipPositions.Where(c => c.MMSI == m.MMSI &&
                    c.LocalRecvTime >= m.FromDateTime && c.LocalRecvTime < m.ToDateTime);
```

You can find the previous row and then compare the time as follows:

```
var ans = from sp in src
          let prev = src.Where(s => s.LocalRecvTime < sp.LocalRecvTime).OrderByDescending(s => s.LocalRecvTime).First().LocalRecvTime
          where prev == null || EF.Functions.DateDiffSecond(prev, sp.LocalRecvTime) >= 10
          select sp;
```

Ideally the definition of `prev` should use `<=` and the primary key to prevent returning the same row, but you didn't provide that information.

Note that this can be exponentially slow if there is a large number of rows to test. In that case, you may be better off returning the rows and processing on the client side or using a SQL stored procedure with `ROWNUMBER`.

Comment: If I use primary key like you said, does it still effect the performance? Because it may process a large number of rows

Comment: @hafizabdullah Using the primary key to restrict the sub-query should help performance immensely if the primary key is ordered - can I expect the primary key to be in chronological ascending `LocalRecvTime` order? I will put in the code change.

Comment: I just checked, sadly no. The primary is not in chronological ascending order to the LocalRecvTime